# Google Tag Manager tracking drop down menu/list (Web app built in R-Shiny)

Tags: r, google-analytics, shiny, google-tag-manager

I have a R Shiny app that I have connected to Google Analytics using Google Tag Manager (R Shiny app means AJAX website). I am currently tracking the standard stuff like PageViews, and have set up a tag to track which Tab a user clicks on (Using Click Element).

In most tabs, I have a drop-down menu/list (can be seen in the picture). When clicking on this list to select/change the input, the click element does not fire. So clicking does not work here.

In the same picture, I have included the source html code. I highlighted what I think is important. The default input is "Age Group (Discrete)." The "option value=" and "selected" changes the input (changed to "Pyramid (Discrete)"). And it also changes in the div class="item" data-value=..." line.

I do not know how to capture when a user changes the input using Google Tag Manager. I am however able to successfully track this if I put this GA code in my JavaScript file.

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function(e) {
  ga('send', 'event', 'widget', 'select data', $(e.currentTarget).val());
});
```

But the above only works if I also have this included:

```
ga('create', 'UA-######', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Which means it is double-counting pageviews (tracking page-views on GTM and the GA code above).

I prefer to track what I want using just GTM. Any help would be appreciated. Let me know if the image is hard to see (May need to zoom in). Thanks

[image: drop-down]
[image: sourcecode]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one possible solutions is using GTM custom events:
1) adjust your code to trigger custom event instead of sending GA event:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function(e) {
  dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'widget data selected',
    'selected_value': $(e.currentTarget).val()
  });
});
```

This will trigger specific `widget data selected` select that can be catched with [Custom Event Trigger](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7679219?hl=en). Then just use that trigger for your regular Analytics Event GTM tag.
Additionally, you might set up [user-defined Data Layer variable](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7683362?hl=en#data_layer) to read the selected option value from dataLayer and use it in your tag.